# Is it possible to integrate outlook, crisp.chat and ringover on Forest Admin?

Tags: forestadmin

We would like to be able to centralize all our communication channels on a client's file to be able to follow-up the exchanges that took place.

This implies seeing the emails (through Outlook) that have been sent to the client, the discussions on the chatbot (crisp.com) and calls/text messages that occurred (Ringover).

I'm not sure if it is possible (maybe through the API?). Have you integrated one of these tools on Forest Admin?

Answer (score 0):

at the moment it's not possible to plug Forest Admin to either Outlook, crisp.com or Ringover.

However, if you have stored these informations (mails / conversation / messages) in your database then you should be able to follow up the exchanges from the Forest Admin UI by implementing the [smart actions](https://docs.forestadmin.com/documentation/reference-guide/actions/create-and-manage-smart-actions) you need.

+ If this type of integrations is critical to you, you can create a feature request on our [productboard](https://portal.productboard.com/forestadmin/1-forest-admin-product-roadmap/tabs/2-ideas-requests)

Last but not least if you are stuck on something or need an answer from the forest admin team you can directly ask on the [community forum](https://community.forestadmin.com/). :)

Kind regards,